# Can’t get ember's application.hbs, or anything else, to render in rails app

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to get a new ember app running in an existing rails app. When I render the root its just a blank page, but the console is showing:

```
 DEBUG: ------------------------------- application.js:12147
 DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3 application.js:12147
 DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3 application.js:12147
 DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1 application.js:12147
 DEBUG: ------------------------------- application.js:12147
 DEPRECATION: register("store", "main") is now deprecated in-favour of register("store:main");
    at Object.Container.register (http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js:18819:17)
    at Application.initializer.initialize (http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js:46015:19)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js:39234:7
    at visit (http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js:38434:3)
    at DAG.topsort (http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js:38488:7)
    at Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend.runInitializers (http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js:39231:11)
    at Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend._initialize (http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js:39188:10)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js:16309:19
    at Object.Ember.handleErrors (http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js:12209:17)
```

My application.hbs has the following:

```
<h1>MOBILE MANAGER</h1>
{{outlet}}
```

And my Mdn(App).js has the following:

```
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./controllers
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./helpers
//= require_tree ./templates
//= require_tree ./routes

window.Mdm = Ember.Application.create();
```

So Ember is clearly loaded but I cant get any templates to render. Thanks for your help!

EDIT::

My application.js is as follows:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from     http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require handlebars
//= require ember
//= require ember-data
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree ./lib
//= require ./app/mdm.js
```

Comment: do you have ember-data also included? and if yes, which version? Make sure to use the latest http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-data-latest.js

Comment: Thanks. I just updated it and it got rid of that large DEPRECATED warning in the console, but still none of my templates are rendering.

Comment: stupid question maybe, but is your `application.hbs` in the `templates` folder you are requiring?

Comment: Not at all, thank you. Ended up being a directory order issue. Thanks for your help.